# Variant of Subset-sum has an $O(1)$ algorithm if $Goldbach$ is true

Tags: reductions, decision-problem

Given $S$ of positive integers $>$ $1$ is there some combination with **even** $SUM$ > $2$ that is **NOT** the sum of two *primes*?

$SUM$ = 10

$S$ = $[4,6]$

$No$,

**Sum of Two Primes**
$5 + 5 = 10$.

**Combination** $4+6=10$

It has an $O(1)$ algorithm if [Goldbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#:%7E:text=Goldbach%27s%20conjecture%20is%20one%20of,the%20sum%20of%20two%20primes.) is True (always output $NO$). Otherwise, it would seem to be NP-complete because it would require solving Subset-Sum.

### Question

Will a many-one-reduction from $Subset-sum$ work for this decision problem in poly-time?

Comment: It's a very special instance of subset sum. I don't see how you'd reduce general subset sum to this particular case.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus As a function problem (output subset-sum with integers) is virtually the same for the general subset-sum with the exception that the answer is always NO if the conjecture is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a finite number of exceptions to the Goldbach conjecture then it is still solvable in linear time.

Note that there is a non-zero probability that the Goldbach conjecture is false. Heuristically, the probability for an infinite number of exceptions is zero.

Comment: Mathematically, has it been proven to be an infinite number of exceptions to the Goldbach Conjecture? (In the sense, $IF$ proven false)? Anyway, thanks for the answer!